# Can't align image?

Tags: html, css, image, alignment

I feel like this is a stupid question, but I honestly cannot figure this out. I can't align an image to the text.
[**kissoff.weebly.com/account-page.html**](http://kissoff.weebly.com/account-page.html)

The box in the center that has 
"ID:78490
Bank:" etc.
should have the image to the right of it. The problem is the image keeps putting itself in the last header on the page and aligning to that instead (it's a picture of a cat with a green border).

Main CSS used for this page:

```
/*ACCOUNT PAGE!*/
#content-container {
    padding-left: 300px;
    padding-top: 70px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 500px;
}

#stats {
    background-color: #FCFCFC;
    width: 500px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(125,180,18,0.8);
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-top: 18px solid rgba(125,180,18,0.8);
}

img.stat-img {
    margin-top: -45px;
    margin-left: 370px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(125,180,18,0.8);
}

#box-container {
    width: 200px;
}

.box {
    background-color: #FCFCFC;
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-left: 1px;
    padding: 5px;
    float: left;
    width: 180px;
    line-height: 5px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(125,180,18,0.8);
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-top: 18px solid rgba(125,180,18,0.8);
}

.box2 {
    background-color: #FCFCFC;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 1px;
    padding: 5px;
    color: #C2BAAF;
    float: left;
    width: 180px;
    line-height: 5px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(125,180,18,0.8);
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-top: 18px solid rgba(125,180,18,0.8);
}

.last-box {
    background-color: #FCFCFC;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    padding: 5px;
    color: #C2BAAF;
    float: left;
    width: 180px;
    line-height: 5px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(125,180,18,0.8);
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-top: 18px solid rgba(125,180,18,0.8);
}

.box-title {
    margin-top: -15px;
    z-index: 900;
    color: #FFF;
}

.box a:link {
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.box a:visited {
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.box a:hover {
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.box a:active {
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.box2 a:link {
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.box2 a:visited {
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.box2 a:hover {
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.box2 a:active {
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.last-box a:link {
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.last-box a:visited {
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.last-box a:hover {
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.last-box a:active {
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

/*ACCOUNT PAGE END!*/
```

Possible CSS issues (the main text containers):

```
#container {
    margin-left: 30px;
    padding-left: 210px;
    padding-top: 70px;
}

#text {
    width: 800px;
    border: 0 solid #000;
    -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
    -moz-border-radius: 30px;
    border-radius: 30px;
}
```

Thanks for looking, I appreciate it.

Comment: post the html as well

Comment: Can you send a link to your website or create an example via JSfiddle?

Comment: LInk is allready posted in question http://kissoff.weebly.com/account-page.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add `position:relative` to the .stat-container class (the container of the img)

then add this css to your .img.stat-img class

```
.img.stat-img
{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

If you want the img to the **far right** of the box then add `position:relative` to the `id="stats"` div instead,  and in your .img.stat-img class use

```
.img.stat-img
{
    position: absolute;
    right: 40px;
    top: 25px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [**corrected**](http://jsfiddle.net/Efcvn/2/) HTML and css sturcture. Please follow the following css and HTML.

**CSS Chagnes**

```
#stats {
    -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
    -moz-border-left-colors: none;
    -moz-border-right-colors: none;
    -moz-border-top-colors: none;
    background-color: #FCFCFC;
    border-color: rgba(125, 180, 18, 0.8);
    border-image: none;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(125, 180, 18, 0.8);
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 18px 1px 1px;
    /*margin-left: 100px;
    margin-top: 20px;*/
    width: 500px;
    float:left;
}
#content-container {
    height: auto;
    margin-left: 30px;
    /*padding-left: 210px;*/
    padding-top: 70px;
}
#stat-container {
    padding:10px;
}
}
img.stat-img {
    border: 1px solid rgba(125, 180, 18, 0.8);
    height: 80px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

**HTML changes**

You need to put cat image outside the div id="stats" not inside it.

Hope it will work for you.